# Ruby - I2C - pi_piper - How to use 4x20 LCD display? - HD44780 with PCF8574 converter

Tags: pi-3, i2c, ruby

Anyone know how I can get use pi_piper gem to use 4x20 LCD display (hd44780) with I2C converter (PCF8574). I'm totally noob in this part of programming.

I tried using ruby-i2c-devices gem, but hd44780 driver didn't work.

Any one know where I can find some examples (projects or guides with gem usage) or drivers for pi_pier gem?

I want to do this in Ruby. Pi-piper gem because it support PWM.

If there are other gems that provide I2C, PWM, 1 wire and GPIO support and have built-in drivers for LCD displays, I can switch to them.

Thanks in advance!